# Angular-Material autocomplete print all Json

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular-material

I'm trying to use the autocomplete directive from angular material using Firebase as database. I have tried to implement the example from their [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPLNwQ)

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainController">

 'data' array: {{data}}

 <md-divider style="margin: 20px"></md-divider>

  Changing this value does not reflect changes to 'data' array:
  <div ng-repeat="dataItem in data track by $index">
   <md-autocomplete md-selected-item="data[$index]" md-search-text="searchText.name" md-items="item in items | filter:searchText" md-item-text="item.name"> 

   <span>{{item.name}}</span> 
 </md-autocomplete> 

  Data item {{$index}} inside ng-repeat: {{dataItem}}</br>

   </div>
```

but when i try to print just the value of *diagnostico.DiagnosticDescription* in my example... print all the id.

my code:

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="diagnostico.DiagnosticDescription" md-search-text="searchText.DiagnosticName" md-items="diagnostico in diagnosticos | filter:searchText" md-item-text="diagnostico.DiagnosticName" placeholder="Search" md-min-length="1" md-clear-button="true"> 
 <span>{{diagnostico.DiagnosticName}}</span>
</md-autocomplete> 
  <md-item-template>
     <span>{{diagnostico.DiagnosticDescription}}</span>
  </md-item-template>
```

my App.js:

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp', ['firebase', 'angucomplete-alt', 'ngclipboard', 'ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']);

myApp.controller('DiagnosticCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray',  function($scope, $firebaseArray){


var myDiagnostic = firebase.database().ref();

$scope.diagnosticos = $firebaseArray(myDiagnostic);

}]);
```

md-autocomplete "working":

[image: md-autocomplete]

but look what print when i select a result:

[image: all the value]

My Firebase database:
[image: Firebase-Database]

Finally, if i use the url with .json to the end i can get what i need.

```
https://diagnosticos-c6b78.firebaseio.com/-KbrsEXh-mWvVBlx__yw/DiagnosticDescription.json
```

The result is what i need print!:

```
"Fraccionar la comida  5 -6 veces por día, porciones controladas y varios grupos de alimentos. Aunque es importante el consumo de frutas y verduras, debe evitar incluir verduras de hoja y color verde como: espinaca, brócoli, lechuga, habichuela, coliflor, estos contribuyen mas a  que se formen cristales de calcio. No mezclar el consumo de leche, yogurt, kumis, queso con alimentos vegetales. Se deben consumir alejados de comidas principales como en media mañana y media tarde.  Evitar consumo de café (tinto o café con leche) Consumir entre 5 -8 vasos de agua por día."
```

Hope that anyone can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well finally i can get the solution, the main problem was that i created an objetct in `md-selected-item="diagnostico.DiagnosticName"`  and i've try to get the data from `diagnostico.DiagnosticDescription`, but the "correct way" will be:

```
diagnostico.DiagnosticName.DiagnosticDescription
```

so, i re-name my `md-selected-item` to: *diagnostico*

finally result:

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="diagnostico" md-search-text="searchText.DiagnosticName" md-items="diagnostico in diagnosticos | filter:searchText" md-item-text="diagnostico.DiagnosticName" placeholder="Search" md-min-length="1" md-clear-button="true">  
<md-item-template>
    <span>{{diagnostico.DiagnosticName}}</span>
    <span>{{diagnostico.DiagnosticDescription}}</span>
</md-item-template>
```

and that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you are trying to do with DiagnosticDescription, but the Angular Material docs show that `md-item-template` should be inside the closing tag of `md-autocomplete` ([example](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.0/api/directive/mdAutocomplete#example-with-not-found-message)).

Try

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="diagnostico.DiagnosticDescription" md-search-text="searchText.DiagnosticName" md-items="diagnostico in diagnosticos | filter:searchText" md-item-text="diagnostico.DiagnosticName" placeholder="Search" md-min-length="1" md-clear-button="true">  
    <md-item-template>
        <span>{{diagnostico.DiagnosticName}}</span>
        <span>{{diagnostico.DiagnosticDescription}}</span>
    </md-item-template>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Is that closer to what you want?

Since you are defining `diagnostico` in the `md-items` attribute of your `md-autocomplete`, `diagnostico` should only be available inside `md-autocomplete`'s closing tag.

Comment: Almost... because with your solution i can print the name and description split ! but the both in the dropdown menu, that i looking for is print the Description outside in a <h4> o <p> tag. But when i "print"  `diagnostico.DiagnosticDescription` outise of md-autocomplete i get the entire json.  Thanks for answer me.